# Bigram vector representations using word2vec

Tags: nlp, word2vec, word-embedding

I want to construct word embeddings for documents using the word2vec tool. I know how to find a vector embedding corresponding to a single word (unigram). Now, I want to find a vector for a bigram. Is it possible to construct a bigram word embedding using word2vec? If yes, how?

Comment: `from gensim.models import Word2Vec, Phrases`

Comment: if the given answer provides a solution for your problem, please accept it to close the issue or comment on why isn't working !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following snippet will get you the vector representation of a bigram. Note that the bigram you want to convert to a vector needs to have an underscore instead of a space between the words, e.g. `bigram2vec(unigrams, "this report")` is wrong, it should be `bigram2vec(unigrams, "this_report")`. For more details on generating the unigrams, please see the `gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec` class [here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html).

```py
from gensim.models import word2vec

def bigram2vec(unigrams, bigram_to_search):
    bigrams = Phrases(unigrams)
    model = word2vec.Word2Vec(bigrams[unigrams])
    if bigram_to_search in model.vocab.keys():
        return model[bigram_to_search]
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: What is `unigrams` here?

Comment: Good question, `unigrams` is the corpus words represented as a list. More details with an example here: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/phrases.html

Comment: Note that `unigrams` must be a list of lists. Further, `model.vocab.keys()` no longer works. It's replaced with `model.wv.index_to_key`