# N-grams in GloVe

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, data-mining, gensim, word-embedding

I want to construct word embeddings for documents using GloVe. I know how to obtain vector embeddings for single words (unigrams) as follows (for their example text document).

```
$ git clone http://github.com/stanfordnlp/glove
$ cd glove && make
$ ./demo.sh
```

Now, I want to obtain vector embeddings for bigrams. For example;

1. "New york" -> instead of "New", and "york"
2. "machine learning" -> instead of "machine", and "learning"

Is it possible to do in GloVe? If yes, how?

Comment: Use the *source*.

Comment: Notice that obtaining embeddings for combinations of words starting from embeddings for single words in definitely non-trivial and an ongoing research topic.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they have available bigram vectors, but you could produce them yourself by preprocessing a corpus. For example if a document in your corpus looks like this:

```
GloVe is love
```

You can format it like this:

```
START_GloVe GloVe_is is_love love_END
```

And train a set of embeddings on this corpus as usual. You could also have a look at Word2vec, like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747245/bigram-to-a-vector) which is similar.